# Apply value from jQuery each loop to each even list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The loop below iterates over a JS object `{ a: 'valueA', b: 'valueB' }`:

```
$.each(xhr, function (key, value) {

});
```

I am trying to apply each value to each **even** list item like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>Description 1</li>
  <li>ValueA</li><!-- Value A from object -->
  <li>Description 2</li>
  <li>ValueB</li><!-- Value B from object -->
</ul>
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Do note that Objects are by definition unordered, so you should expect to sometimes get `<li>Description 1</li>
  <li>ValueB</li>
  <li>Descriotion 2</li>
  <li>ValueA</li>`

Comment: `$.each(xhr, function (key, value) { $('#ul').append('<li>' + key + '</li><li>' + value + '</li>'); });`? It's a bit confusing what exactly you mean by "apply each value to each even list item".

Comment: Do you mean you would like to create a new unordered list, then populate it with keys and values as individual list items  where the key is the odd list item and the value is the even listen item? Or, are all of the keys already populated and you are trying to set the value for each key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I misread your question, here is what I believe youre asking for

```
var xhr = { a: 'valueA', b: 'valueB'}
var index = 1;

$.each(xhr, function (key, value) {
  $('ul li:eq(' + index + ')').html(value);
  index = index + 2; 
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/32xdjwry/

Comment: JavaScript objects are unordered, this may end with incorrect results.

Comment: My question wasn't very clear from the start - my fault apologies. Thanks for  the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`$('li:even')` should do the job! (Answers the original title question: "*Apply value from jQuery each loop to every even list item*")

---

> **EDIT:**   what the OP was actually asking for is to iterte over the object using each and assign parameters to even elements sequentially
>
> ```
> $.each(xhr, function (key, value) {
>   $('li:nth-child(2n+1)')...
> });
> ```

*N.B.  You may want to add some specificity to the jQuery selector lest you be applying your actions to all instances of `<li>` elements on the page*

Comment: Wont this apply each value to the first matched even list item. Instead of traversing down each even list item and applying the value?

Comment: Ahah, that indeed is true.  I what you're trying to do now, amending my answer accordingly, although it would help others if the question was reworded slightly to more accurately reflect your question

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This can also be achieved using a count. E.g. `count++` and then `'li:nth-of-type('+count * 2+')'`.

Comment: True, but why add a var for `count` needlessly? :-)

Comment: JavaScript objects are unordered, this may end with incorrect results.

Comment: Just another way of doing it - that's all.